# Google SSO without a qualified top level domain for testing purposes

Tags: docker, google-sso

I want to test out google sso in my local dev environment before pushing to production.

However the Authorized Javascript Origins will not allow me to add the URI because it does not have a valid top level domain.

`mytestenvironment.localbx`

Because I cannot add the URI I get

`Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`

Any suggestions or do I have to fix the environment to end in `.com | .dog`  ?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ngrok.com can expose the localhost to the internet! gives my localhost the tld of .io.